# Oracle APEX : How to refresh the page after submit - before Branching

Tags: refresh, oracle-apex

I have an APEX page, with a interactive report with Check boxes and a Button on top.
On click of button, It is performing some PLSQL process (on selected rows that are checked) and in a branch I'm invoking a Report Query which downloads a report in the pdf format.
But even after downloading the report, the report is not automatically getting refreshed. 
Ideally I want to remove the processed rows from the report so as to avoid multiple processing by clicking the button continuously. 
But since I have a branch that goes to download the report, it is not going to other branches that comes after in sequence to refresh the page.
Can anyone tell me how to refresh the page/or just that region after the processing? Thanks.